# How do I execute an async piece of code after another async piece of code has finished executing in java (sequentially)?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-sleep, java-threads

I have the following pieces of code:

1)

```
int operationCnt = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < operationCnt; i++) { // for every instruction
    final int curOperation = i;
    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // execute something on the UI thread

            if (curOperation == operationCnt) {
                // Execution has finished RUN THE NEXT PIECE OF CODE SOMEHOW
            }

        }
    })
}
```

2)

```
int operationCnt2 = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < operationCnt2; i++) { // for every instruction
    final int curOperation = i;
    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // execute something on the UI thread

            if (curOperation == operationCnt2) {
                // Execution has finished WRAP IT UP
            }

        }
    })
}
```

I want to make sure that **operation 1 runs first**, then right **after it finishes operation 2 runs**.
Finally I'd love to be able to run some code after both have finished.

(I want those two to execute sequentially - strictly one after the other)

In other languages that is easy, but I'm not sure what the cleanest way would be to implement the same logic in Java?

Please shed some light.

Thank you

Comment: there is a method in AsyncTask called as onPostExecute() here call your another async task

Comment: take this as an example -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671602/6142219

Comment: I know that, but I thought AsyncTask was meant for background running services, and I'm not sure wether it's a good idea to dispatch a UI thread operation from the doInBackground method. What do you think?

Comment: Use Java `Executor Framework`, `Future` will be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `operationCnt` to control the thread-flow like that. Variable `i` use in `runner` must be final.

You can use `Thread.join()` to wait:

```
Runnable r = () -> // do something;
Thread t = new Thread(r);
t.start();
Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
...
t.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();
```

// After the program reach here. All thread `t_i` are finished. You can start operation 2

If you don't want to block on main thread, then you can use `CompletableFuture`:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> your first operation)
.thenRun(() -> Your second operation);
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you elaborate a bit more based on the code I posted above? I'd be grateful.

Comment: For operation 1, are you going to execute post(runnable) 10 times?

Comment: Yes, is it preferable to post once and run the for loop inside?

Comment: It depends, if you want to run a task 10 times then post it 10 times, nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run one operation asynchronously, then run the second one after the first finishes, then why use two Runnables and two post calls? You can just combine them into one.

If you want to run the first N times

```
post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // do operation 1
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // do operation 2
        }
   }
});
```

or

```
post(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // do operation 1
            // do operation 2
        }
   }
});
```